# How would you convert a char array to an array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on an assignment and am kind of stumped. The goal of the assignment is to read part names from txt document and put them into a parts structure. I've used `fgets()` to put the information into a `char` array but now am unsure how to convert that into the structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct part
{
    char pname[25];
    char pnumber[8];
    double weight;
    char supplier1[5];
    char supplier2[5];
    int in_stock;
} Part;

void main()
{
    Part partlist[100];
    char buffer[260];
    FILE *fp; 
    int i = 0;
    fp = fopen("part_data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
    }
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        if (fgets(buffer,260,fp)) {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);
}
```

An example of the data I am trying to put in the structure is this:

```
antenna          4553-02 1.9800 A123 B021  12
ratchet          2347-01 0.8725 A007 B021  49
seatbelt         1987-01 0.4310 A333 B001  61
pin              5637-03 0.0351 A007 B010 146
wing assembly    2372-02 6150.0 A333 B021   4
```

Comment: Determine what fields are needed for the structure. Second define the structure.

Answer (score 1):

If the part names do not contain any digits, this might work. fscanf will scan the file as long at it successfully reads six items. `%24[ a-zA-Z]` will skip leading whitespace and read up to 24 upper or lower case letters and spaces. `%7s` will read up to seven characters to next whitespace. `%lf` will read a double, `%4s` will read up to four characters to next whitespace. `%d` will read integer. When fscanf fails to read six items ( probably reached EOF) the while loop will end and the file will be closed.

```
int i = 0;
fp = fopen("part_data.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file.\n");
}
else {
    while ( ( fscanf ( fp, " %24[ a-zA-Z] %7s %lf %4s %4s %d"
    , partlist[i].pname, partlist[i].pnumber, &partlist[i].weight           
    , partlist[i].supplier1, partlist[i].supplier2, &partlist[i].in_stock)) == 6) { 
        i++;
        if ( i >= 99) {
            break; // exit so as to not exceed array limits
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Structure is coll'n of various types. and you have only one type which is char array. your data is in single data type like string. might be your question is not very clear. if you want to add a many parts of string in many variables refer from same structure. then it is possible.